# Tomcat certificate issue

Tags: ssl, tomcat, certificate, keystore, ca

I configured ssl on tomcat with the below steps.

1. imported the cert to jks

   keytool -import -alias *.company.com -trustcacerts -file  D:\OpenText\keystore\star_company_com_vm1.p7b -keystore D:\OpenText\keystore\server_company_com.jks
2. configured web.xml

[image]

When I open the deufalt page within the server with FQDN of server(like server.domain.com), the certificate loads properly.
[image]

But if I open outside of the server(internet) by dns url(like dns.domain.com), certificate not trusted issue arise.

[image]

The generated certificate has CN as *.domain.com and SAN as *.domain.com and individual dns fqdn urls . The url which have the cert issue is exactly the same as mentioned in SAN. what could be the issue ?

Keystore list:

[image]

Comment: You did import the certificate with an alias of `*.company.com`, while your server's configuration (which should text, not an image BTW) uses the `server` alias. Can you list the entries in your keystore (`keytool -list -keystore <file>`) and add the result to the question?

Comment: FYI, using same alias (image changed again ) <Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="*.company.com" keystoreFile="conf\server_company_com.jks" keystorePass="test" />

Comment: added the keystore list image. *.company.com exits.

Comment: Are you sure the certificate contains the `SAN` extension? The browser says it is missing.

Comment: yeah. SAN contains the same dns URL which is loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved after importing PFX cert on web gateway